# Run a query in foreach loop with Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables, 1 to define avaliable time period and 1 to store reservations.

Each time period has it's own capacity, user after submiting the date is rerouted to a differerent form where he selects time, options come from the "avaliable_time" table.

Before actually showing him all the options I want to check what options are avaliable, meaning to check the repetition of the time period in reservations on a selected date and if it repeats itself the same number of times as the capacity for the time period is then get it from the database.

Meaning to do so I should run a query in a foreach loop and return an array of time periods, but I'm unable to do so.

```php
public function time()
{
    $capacity = AvaliableTime::select('capacity')->get();

    return view('public.time', [
        "banned_time" => Reservation::where('reservation_date', '=' . $_GET['date'])
            ->groupBy('reservation_time')
            ->having(Reservation::raw('count(reservation_time)'), '>=' . $capacity)
            ->pluck('reservation_time')
    ]);
}
```

This was my first attempt, the problem is it checks for the entire array, not for each value in the array

> [{"capacity":2},{"capacity":4}]

This is the array that i get as the `$capacity`
So how do i check it in a foreach loop and return the array

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand all the details of what you're asking but look into _scopes_. Sounds like you need to set up a scope named _available_ that returns open time slots.

Comment: Why you don't use relationships ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships